# Counting elements in a chain MySQL

Tags: mysql

Say we have a table which has two columns, `id` and `id_parent`. The field `id_parent` references to an `id` of the same table. If `id_parent` is `NULL`, we consider that entry to be the first element of a chain.

The question is: is there a query to get the different chains and how many elements are there in each one?

E.g., given the table

```
id    id_parent
1     NULL
2     NULL
3     1
4     3
5     NULL
6     5
7     4
```

The output would be

```
id_first_el   num_of_els
1             4
2             1
5             2
```

Constraints: no circularity, no bifurcations (`id_parent` is unique).